# Fetch out all Favorited records

Tags: php, yii

i have three tables

1) tbl_users -> id, name

2) tbl_entries -> id, title, details, user_id

2) tbl_favorites -> id, user_id, entry_id

I just want to fetch out all favorite entries of any user using Yii.

I am using dataprovider to achieve it and it gives all records of Entries table but i want to to show only those records which are added in favorites table.

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Entries', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 15,
    ),
    ));
```

plz help.

---

i just got mysql query for the same purpose but want to implement in yii style

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_entries, tbl_favorites  where tbl_entries.id = tbl_favorites.entry_id and tbl_favorites.user_id = xx
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve this is by correctly defining your [Models-Relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship) (& this [wiki post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/) is also good), I am not sure of your business logic but i will assume the following:

1. **User** `has-many` **Entry**
2. **User** `has-many` **Favorite**
3. **Entries** `belongs-to` **User**
4. **Entry** `has-one` **Favorite**
5. **Favorite** `belongs-to` **Entry**
6. **Favorite** `belongs-to` **User**

***Tip:** Name your relations so it make sense later, e.g #1 should be entries while #3 should be entry*

So, having a `user_id` you need to:

1. Fetch User record
2. Fetch that's user favorites
3. For all the results from (2), fetch corresponding entries

The code will look something like:

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk($user_id); //Fetch user record
$favorites = $user->favorites; // Fetch the user favorites using relations #2 & #6

// Getting entries
$entries = array(); // empty array to store entries

foreach($favorites as $fav) do
{
  $entries[] = $fav->entry; // Fetch entry record using relations #4 & #5
}
....
// Pass $entries array to your view
```